# Active Admin ruby multiple select for values in an array

Tags: ruby, activeadmin, multi-select

So we have a users table. And we have a account_managers table which belongs to a user. On the users table, there is a role column which is an array  that has one or multiple roles a User might have. This select is on the AM edit page. How would I have it to pre-select the roles in the array for the associated user and allow multiple selected values? I tried this but it doesn't work

```
  f.input :role, as: :select, 
    multiple: true, 
    collection: ["admin", "reporting", "user", "team_lead"], 
    selected: f.object.user.try(:role)
    :input_html => { :value => f.object.user.try(:role) }
```